# SQL - Insert row into same table where column has distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to add a waterproofing service to a database of services. I want to add the service once for each device based upon wether or not it is an in-store service. Here is what I have currently:

```
INSERT INTO services (serviceID, manufacturer, deviceName, serviceName, price, upc)
SELECT
    DEFAULT,
    manufacturer,
    DISTINCT deviceName,
    'Waterproofing Stand-alone',
    '59.99',
    '00813583026318'
FROM services
WHERE deviceName NOT LIKE '%(In-store)%';
```

Please let me know if this will produce the desired effect.

Thanks

Comment: What is the "desired efffect?"  Can you show us by way of sample data what you are trying to insert?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.giganticsocial.com/db.png).

Comment: see image above. I want to add 1 row for each of the devices that has a waterproofing service

Comment: The image does not clarify your question.  Show us the data you start with, and how you want to use it to insert the actual data.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.giganticsocial.com/db2.png).

this show how it should be after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how distinct works. Distinct returns unique combination of the values of all the selected columns.

Assuming serviceId is an auto incrementing column, you can use aggregation and use max (or min) on the other columns to get only one row per deviceName.

```
insert into services (
    manufacturer,
    deviceName,
    serviceName,
    price,
    upc
    )
select max(manufacturer),
    deviceName,
    'Waterproofing Stand-alone',
    '59.99',
    '00813583026318'
from services
where deviceName not like '%(In-store)%'
group by deviceName;
```

If there can be only one manufacturer per deviceName, then you don't need a group by. Just the `DISTINCT` should be fine:

```
insert into services (
    manufacturer,
    deviceName,
    serviceName,
    price,
    upc
    )
select distinct manufacturer,
    deviceName,
    'Waterproofing Stand-alone',
    '59.99',
    '00813583026318'
from services
where deviceName not like '%(In-store)%';
```

Comment: This will add 1 service for each distinct deviceName?

Comment: I agree with this bloke.  Use group by -- not distinct.

Comment: @ggntc - Yes it should produce unique devicename with one service. But which exactly - whatever the aggregate function will produce. If that's not what you want, add sample data and expected output in your question along with explanation.

Comment: `DISTINCT` might work, or it might not, the OP isn't clear enough to say.

Comment: @ggntc - In the image you posted, I can see there are multiple rows with different different service ID. WHich row out of those do you want to insert? (may be with max or min serviceID?)?

Comment: see the after image above

Comment: Each device "deviceName" has multiple services. I want this to insert a waterproofing service for each of the devices.

Comment: @ggntc - Is ServiceId an autoincrement column? Also, is there only one manufacturer per deviceName?

Comment: yes to ai and yes only one Manu

Comment: @ggntc - Both solutions should be fine for you.

Comment: @GurV I see you pulled out the serviceID. Is that because it is AI?

Comment: @ggntc- Yes. That is why.

Comment: The second version worked perfect. Thx.

Comment: @ggntc - Glad it helped. Please consider marking the answer accepted if it helped. There is no obligation to do this however.